# How can I limit joinLeft() results in doctrine?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I'm working in Symfony and I have little question.

Is it possible to limit elements joined by `joinLeft()` in doctrine query builder?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do it with query builder.

You can use [NativeSQL](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html) or make several requests. Depends on your needs.